# Way too slow to scrape loop-inside-loop with Python BeautifulSoup/urllib2

Tags: performance, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I would like to scrape a large portion of a site. Say, the general url structure would be as follows:

https://ExampleSite.com/XXXXX, where X can be any number or upper-case alphabet.
i.e. https://ExampleSite.com/32E4Z, https://ExampleSite.com/AA44P

The total character possibility is 36 including numbers and alphabets. Since there are 5 random slots, the total url combinations become a scary 36^5 = 60,466,176. Out of these links, only a small fraction (20%) actually have a valid page, other combinations of the url based on the "examplesite.com" front return invalid links which I do not scrape anything (but I guess I still need to check to see if that combination of URL is or isn't valid and contain the "Specific heading"?).

Here is my Python/BeautifulSoup code which is working, my goal is to going through these url combinations and extract the valid links matched the "Specific heading":

```
import urllib2
import re
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import threading

def get_Siteinfo(varURLpart1, varURLpart2, varURLpart3, varURLpart4, varURLpart5):

    for loop1 in range(0, varURLpart1): 
        for loop2 in range(0, varURLpart2):
            for loop3 in range(0, varURLpart3):
                for loop4 in range(0, varURLpart4):
                    for loop5 in range(0, varURLpart5):

                        URLchar = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
                            "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M",
                            "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"] # len(URLchar) = 36

                        url1 = "https://ExampleSite.com/"
                        urlComplete  = url1 + str(URLchar[loop1]) + str(URLchar[loop2]) + \
                            str(URLchar[loop3]) + str(URLchar[loop4]) + str(URLchar[loop5])

                        page = urllib2.urlopen(urlComplete)
                        soup_SomeSiteURL = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
                        page.close()

                        Subhead = soup_SomeSiteURL.find("span", class_="subhead")
                        if Subhead: # If-statement solution; if "subhead" class is found
                            SubheadString = Subhead.get_text(strip=True) # then extract the string
                            if SubheadString == "Specific heading":
                                saveFile = open('SomeSiteValidURLs.csv', 'a')
                                saveFile.write(str(urlComplete)+'\n')
                                saveFile.close()

                        loop5 += 1
                    loop4 += 1
                loop3 += 1
            loop2 += 1
        loop1 += 1

get_Siteinfo(36, 36, 36, 36, 36)
```

My problems are the slow processing speed and the burden of going through many invalid links. I found that each url requires ~1 second to go through, to work the math out, 60,466,176 combinations will take about 2 full years with my computer on all the time. This is obviously non-applicable. So my questions are:

- Am I doing it wrong with loops inside loops?
- Any way to avoid the needs to go through invalid links quickly or altogether?
- Would regex help?
- My next step is to implement multithread. Though, I have tried it in other program, while it works, it only cuts the processing time by half, so it will still require a full year of running the program non-stop.
- Or any other tips I can speed up the process?

Answer (score 0):

This is an I/O bound task.  That means that the speed of your computer doesn't matter much, because what's taking the most time (by orders of magnitude) is I/O (waiting on http requests).  There's probably not much you can do to get the requests back faster.  Multithreading will help, but as you said, only by a factor of 2 to 4 or so.

Your best bet would be to see if you can find a list of the valid urls without trying them all.  Maybe you can find this somewhere else on the site?  If not, maybe contact the site administrator?

Aside from that, this isn't much different from trying every possible password to hack into someone's account...

If you really mus try all of them, then one option might be to create lots of virtual servers through a VPS hosting company.  Depending on how they limit traffic to a certain domain, you could potentially cut it down to a month or less if you have 12 servers running.  Also, that way you wouldn't have to have your own machine doing it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions I will look into them further. There is a possible "solution" I came up in mind. For example, instead of doing all the loops in one python script, maybe I can create, say 12 scripts that cover all the 60,466,176 combinations without overlaps. And then just run these 12 scripts non-stop for a month, then combine the csv files together into one. Do you think it's feasible and will speed up by a factor of ~12?

Comment: No, that won't be more of an advantage than multithreading, because the amount of http traffic your connection can handle at one time is limited.  Also, be careful, because ExampleSite might ban your IP if they're getting a huge number of requests from you.